# int 80 doesn't appear in assembly code

Tags: c, system-calls

**Problem**

Let's consider:

```
int main(){
write(1, "hello", 5);
return 0;
}
```

I am reading a book that suggests the assembly output for the above code should be:

```
main:
mov $4, %eax
mov $1 %ebx
mov %string, %ecx
mov $len, %edx
int $0x80
```

(The above code was compiled with 32 bit architecture. Passing arguments by registers isn't caused by '64 bit convention passing arguments by registers' but it is caused by the fact, we make a syscall. )

And the output on my 64 bit Ubuntu machine with: `gcc -S main.c -m32`
is:

```
pushl   $4
pushl   $string
pushl   $1
call    write
```

**My doubts**

So it confused me. Why did gcc compile it as "normal" call, not as syscall.
In this situation, what is the way to make the processor use a kernel function (like write)?

Comment: gcc is not guaranteed to comply with your book.  It is compiling it along with the call to `write`, which is library function/wrapper. Which will probably call this `int`. Or it won't...

Comment: What happens with optimizations ?

Comment: GCC doesn't inline system calls, it just calls the function defined in the C runtime library. The function in C runtime library invokes the system call, though as Eugene said, it may not use `int $0x80`.

Comment: the posted/expected code looks like something from back in the days of DOS.  and in modern linux, 80hex (128) is the number for the ' sys_init_module' function and not the write function.  More likely the desired number is 146, the 'sys_writev' function

Comment: @user3629249: All syscalls are `int $0x80`. The syscall number is in `%eax`.

Comment: Thanks! Where can I see a write's implementation?

Comment: @J.Doe: `gdb /lib/libc.so.6` `disass write`

Comment: ok, I know it. But can I find function in C? After all, linux is opensource.

Comment: You could download the source for glibc.

Comment: @J.Doe In glibc, the syscall wrappers are implemented in assembly, so you won't find a C implementation. The assembly code for the wrappers is also [generated by a script](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/unix/make-syscalls.sh;h=fbf96605e016230e6f888bb5c145dbab5efc1ceb;hb=HEAD).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am reading a book that suggests the assembly output for the above code should be ...

You shouldn't believe everything you read :-)

There is no *requirement* that C code be turned into specific assembly code, the only requirement that the C standard mandates is that the resulting code behave in a certain manner.

Whether that's done by *directly* calling the OS system call with `int $80` (or `sysenter`), or whether it's done by calling a library routine `write()` which *eventually* calls the OS in a similar fashion, is largely irrelevant.

If you were to locate and disassemble the `write()` code, you may well find it simply reads those values off the stack into registers and then calls the OS in much the same way as the code you've shown containing `int $80`.

---

As an aside, what if you wanted to port `gcc` to a totally different architecture that uses `call 5` to do OS-level system calls. If `gcc` is injecting specific `int $80` calls into the assembly stream, that's not going to work too well.

But, if it's injecting a call to a `write()` function, all you have to do is make sure you link it with the correct library containing a modified `write()` function (one that does `call 5` rather than `int $80`).